# How to retain the field Editor after editing the cell in a NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

`Added  detailed info`

I have two Windows.(mainWindow and childWindow.) On the top of the `mainWindow` I added `childwindow` using WindowController using the following Code, so that the `childwindow` is always on the top of `mainWindow`.

`[[childWindowController window]setLevel:NSModalPanelWindowLevel];`

In the ChildWindow I have a tableView,When I doubleclick on this tableView `row` I would like to update the tableview in the mainWindow. I used the following  api of tableview for editing.

`-(void)editColumn:(NSInteger)columnIndex row:(NSInteger)rowIndex withEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent select:(BOOL)flag`

After that I would like edit the contents of the tableview in the mainWindow. I am not able get the keyboard focus in the tableviewcell as the 'childWindow' is always the 'FirstResponder'.

How would I make the tableview in the 'mainWindow' as the `FirsResponder` or is there any way to  get the 'keyboardfocus' in the tableviecell of the 'mainwindow'

Comment: I don't think ["Field Editor"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/FieldEditor.html) means what you think it means. Could you add some detail to what you're trying to do? Maybe a graphical description?

Comment: Now Iam able to get the fieldEditor in the tableviewcell using the following code NSText * currentEditor = [tableView currentEditor];
    [mainWindow makeFirstResponder: currentEditor];
    [currentEditor setSelectedRange: NSMakeRange([[currentEditor string] length],0)];

Comment: I need to implement the textDidEndEditing Delegate. If I implement this one setObjectValue of tableview delegate is not getting called. How can I make the both things work together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to call `[super textDidEndEditing]`. This solved the issue.